# How to limit applying to particular directories when invoking Terragrunt's `run-all` command?

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I am curious if there is a way to exclude some directories from Terragrunt's `run-all` command. The documentation is [here](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/execute-terraform-commands-on-multiple-modules-at-once/#the-run-all-command).

For example, instead of queuing all directories for `destroy` with the following output when running `terragrunt run-all destroy`:

```
INFO[0000] The stack at /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production will be processed in the following order for command destroy:
Group 1
- Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/us-west-2/acm-generic-co-tld
- Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/us-west-2/athena-saas-alb
- Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/us-west-2/ecr
- Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/us-west-2/elasticcache-redis-saas
- Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/us-west-2/kms-rds
- Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/us-west-2/rds-saas
- Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/us-west-2/s3
- Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/us-west-2/waf

Group 2
- Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/us-west-2/bastion
- Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/us-west-2/eks-saas
- Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/us-west-2/secrets-manager

Group 3
 - Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/global/route53
 - Module /Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production/us-west-2/vpc
```

I would want to exclude destroying `ecr` and `s3`.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the solution was just in the [docs](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/execute-terraform-commands-on-multiple-modules-at-once/#the-run-all-command:%7E:text=%2D%2Dterragrunt%2Dexclude%2Ddir)! There is a flag `--terragrunt-exclude-dir` which can be used for each directory I wanted to exclude. So my command became:

```
terragrunt run-all destroy --terragrunt-exclude-dir us-west-2/ecr --terragrunt-exclude-dir us-west-2/s3
```

when running from the `/Users/user/dev/terraform/aws-main-account/production` directory.